# Approximating integrals using Monte Carlo simulation in R

Tags: r, self-study, monte-carlo

How do I approximate the following integral using MC simulation?

$$
\int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-1}^{1} |x-y| \,\mathrm{d}x \,\mathrm{d}y
$$

Thanks!

**Edit** (Some context): I am trying to learn how to use simulation to approximate integrals, and am getting some practice done when I ran into some difficulties.

**Edit 2+3**: Somehow I got confused and thought I needed to split the integral into separate parts. So, I actually figured it out:

```
n <- 15000
x <- runif(n, min=-1, max=1)
y <- runif(n, min=-1, max=1)
mean(4*abs(x-y))
```

Comment: Why would you want to approximate this via Monte Carlo when it can easily be solved explicitly?

Comment: Because it's a case where there's a known answer, which is handy when learning simulation to make sure you've done it right?

Comment: Or in my admittedly weird case, because your brain *works* via simulation, which means even elaborate simulations are easier than theoretically straightforward analytical solutions. *mutter*

Comment: @EpiGrad: I'm aware of the possible answers here, including your first very important comment. (The intent of my comment is to politely and indirectly encourage the OP to add a little bit of context to the question they are asking. When context is provided, it generally leads to better answers. I [generally] prefer this approach to more direct ones.)

Comment: @cardinal Fair. And agreed - OP, some context would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry guys, I should have provided more context. EpiGrad is right, I'm trying to learn how to use simulation and I'm more concerned about the method than the answer. So helpful pointers in the right direction would be great.

Comment: Can you edit your question and elaborate on where the difficulties lie? What part(s) are you confused or unsure about? What parts *are* you sure about? Is there an example that you *do* get so that we can see what the source of confusion might be. (Also, if this is from a homework or assignment, please kindly add the `homework` tag during your edit.) I look forward to reading more! Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. What about this particular example do you find confusing? That's what I was trying to get at with my previous comments. Apologies if this seems like I'm being obtuse. That's not my intent. Can you give an example you *do* understand how to calculate?

Comment: No worries cardinal. I just wasn't thinking clearly and thought I needed to split the integral into separate parts for dx and dy. I think i figured it out and posted my solution above.

Comment: You are on the right track! The answer you give is *very* close to being correct. You're missing one tiny part. (**Hint**: What is the pdf of a $\mathcal U(-1,1)$ random variable)?

Comment: It's 0.5. So I need to multiply by two 2's to give: 'mean(4*abs(x-y))'. Did I finally get it?

Comment: (+1) **Yes**! :) You may have to wait a few (8?) hours, but you should consider coming back and placing your edit into an answer so that other users (like me) can upvote it. Welcome to the site! I hope to see you continue to participate here. Cheers. :)

Comment: One point to add: I find [maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/) extremely useful for symbolic math.  If I had to do analytical calculations myself, I'd have the same problem as @EpiGrad.  But in maxima, you could do `integrate(integrate(abs(x-y), y, -1, 1), x, -1, 1);` and get the answer 8/3.

Comment: For the R interested, though not as elegant at the maxima code posted by Karl, one can do `integrate(Vectorize(function(y) integrate(function(x) abs(x-y), -1, 1)$value), -1, 1)` and get a numeric approximation. Using the [cubature](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cubature/index.html) package `adaptIntegrate(function(x) abs(x[1] - x[2]), c(-1, -1), c(1, 1))` can be used. This is just to give a couple of ideas for numeric evaluation of integrals that could come in handy, for instance when testing if a simulation works correctly.

Comment: @MyName: Please consider posting an answer to your question. Others can then upvote and eventually you can accept it or any other answer you like that comes along. But, since you were able to solve your own problem, you should share that experience with others via an answer, in my opinion.

Comment: Note that you can estimate the variance of your estimation and use it to give a confidence interval: using your code a 95% CI is given by `4*(mean(abs(x-y)) + c(-1,1)*1.96*sd(abs(x-y))/sqrt(n))`

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, a low dimensional integral like that is usually more efficiently done via deterministic quadrature instead of Monte Carlo. Monte Carlo comes into its own at about 4 to 6 dimensions. Got to learn it in low dimensions first, of course...

Comment: I guess that's why this question is tagged [tag:Homework] :-).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in Excel with [Tukhi](http://tukhi.com).

Enter

```
=tukhi.average(abs(2*rand()-1 - (2*rand()-1)))
```

and hit the run button.